# How To Get URL Parameters in django mako template?

Tags: django, django-templates, mako

I have url like this,

`blablabla.com/home?public=true`

how can I get the value `public` in django mako template?

I previously using `request.path` but it's just show '/home' as a string

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should get value from `request.GET` dictionary. Take `request.GET['public']`